# jq on non-well-formed JSON file

Tags: json, jq

So, a program I'm using dumped its data in a quasi-JSON like this:

```
{"id": "A0001", "weight": 10.5, "category": "A"}
{"id": "A0002", "weight": 8.0, "category": "A"}
{"id": "A0001", "weight": 22.3, "category": "B"}
```

As you can see, it has JSON dictionary *per line* instead of wrapped in a list.

Can `jq` handle this kind of malformed JSON?

Answer (score 2):

`jq` does not consider this invalid JSON but as several independent but concatenated JSON documents. Each of these will be piped through the filters by each own (by default). So

```
jq '.id' input.json
```

will also return three indenpendent outputs:

```
"A0001"
"A0002"
"A0001"
```

However you can use `-s` or `--slurp` to wrap all these into a top-level array and process that as one input'. So

```
jq --slurp 'map(.id)' input.json
```

will return

```
[
  "A0001",
  "A0002",
  "A0001"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it w/o jq, just using unix cli:

```
bash $ echo [ $(<file.json paste -s -d, -) ]
[ {"id": "A0001", "weight": 10.5, "category": "A"},{"id": "A0002", "weight": 8.0, "category": "A"},{"id": "A0001", "weight": 22.3, "category": "B"} ]
bash $
```

the resulting output is a valid JSON.